# selenium web driver should stop execution of last element

Tags: selenium

I am new to selenium and was trying to make my work automated. My results consists of pagination like next page. At last page "Next" button is disabled and my code should not access that particular element.

```
List<WebElement> pagesize = driver.findElements(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[3]/div/span"));
while(true) {
    for(int i=5; i<=pagesize.size(); i++) {
        WebElement Analystelem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[3]/div["+i+"]/span"));
        List<WebElement> pagesize = driver.findElements(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[3]/div/span"));
        System.out.println(pagesize.size());

        while(true) {
            for(int i=5;i<=pagesize.size();i++) {
                WebElement Analystelem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[3]/div["+i+"]/span"));
                if(elementpage.isEnabled()) {
                    elementpage.click();
                }
                else {
                    System.exit(1);
                }
```

note: older search is the next button here. 
at last page of results i am getting an exception as

```
"Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[3]/div[10]/span"}"
```

Comment: we can't help you unless you post the relevant HTML tha you are trying to find. post that, and we'll be happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I doubt that you have searched for a span and stored its reference to 'Analystelem' but you are calling a click action on 'elementpage'.

If the code you provided is working than below given code will work fine. When Selenium will find the element and tries to click on it; it will throw exception, handle the exception as you feel best but it will not break your execution.

Just put your code in Try Catch block like this:

```
while(true)
{
for(int i=5;i<=pagesize.size();i++)
{
    WebElement Analystelem=driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[3]/div["+i+"]/span"));
    if(elementpage.isEnabled())
    {
        Try
        {
               elementpage.click();
        }
        Catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Do whatever you want to do here
        }
    }
    else
    {
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
}
```

Additionally, you do not have to check weather the element is enabled or not. Let the try catch do its work. More suited code:

```
while(true)
{
for(int i=5;i<=pagesize.size();i++)
{
    WebElement Analystelem=driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[3]/div["+i+"]/span"));
    Try
    {
        elementpage.click();
    }
    Catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.exit(1);
        //Do whatever you want to do here
    }
}
}
```